# dropdown menu onclick go back to the top of the webpage

Tags: javascript, css

i have this simple html code

```
<html>
<body>
<select name="country" id="country">
<option value="1">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
<option value="2">canada</option>
<option value="3">Finland</option>
<option value="4">France</option>
<option value="5">United Kingdom</option>
<option selected="selected" value="12">United States</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

if this dropdown menu is in the bottom of a webpage, and whenever the user selects one of the options on the menu, the user automatically go to the top of the webpage without reloading, i know it's simple but i could't do it, hope you help me guys, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `head` of your file, place this little snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("country").onchange = function(){
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        };
    };
</script>
```

There's no need to load jQuery for a simple action such as this; it's pointless to include such a large file for something Vanilla JavaScript can handle with ease.

Answer (score 1):

This should take care of it for you... Add this to your `<head>`

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("select#country").change(function() {
          $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
          return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your responce, but i'm not sure where to put that code exactly, sorry i'm just new to all of this.